# Loading a fully self contained website w/ .js and .css includes in Phonegap & JQuery Mobile (Android)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, cordova, external

I'm having issues loading an external link to a mini website in my Android app (with includes that load).  A little background... I'm loading html5 output with a full directory of images, .js  and css files that style the mini site.  I can properly OPEN the link in the InAppBrowser, however the .js and .css includes within the mini site don't seem to be loading.  How can I load these .js includes and treat this external link as its own entity, like a normal browser would?

I need to use "InAppBrowser" in Phonegap so they can return to the app after they've visited the mini site (these are web-based training courses, which is why they have their own images, css, js etc).

Here is the code used to open the site (which DOES open the URL correctly, but no .js includes get loaded):

```
window.open(value, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you go for a ChildBrowser Plugin.
It's available [here.](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser/2.0.0)

I have added this to my project too. Works like a charm !
There are `.java` and `.js` files with some `icons` too. You can customize it according to your needs !

Have Fun.

Comment: thanks Mast3rmind, but I've read that ChildBrowser has been deprecated:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/_childbrowser_plugin_deprecating_use_inappbrowser.

Comment: [See This](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/06/20/coming-soon-phonegap30/)
Its coming back in version 3.0 as an API! So stay Tuned ! ;)